# Crop camera before streaming to a NetStream in Flash

Tags: flash, camera, webcam, crop, rtmp

I'm building a very simple publisher for the webcam in Flash. I want to select a camera and send the stream to a RTMP URL, basically:

```
Camera camera = Camera.getCamera();
NetStream ns = new NetStream(connection);
ns.attachCamera(camera);
ns.publish("stream name");
```

Now, I know I can set a mode on the camera, like this:

```
camera.setMode(320, 240, 25);
```

But what I really would like to do is to set a mode such as 360 x 480 (not the same aspect ratio as the camera is recording) and have Flash crop the image for me. Is there a way to do that?

**Edit:** I know [Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html) can do this, but I would like to do it in the browser.

According to the [ActionScript docs for Camera.setMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29), there is an optional fourth parameter that sounds interesting, `favorArea`. From the docs:

> **favorArea**:`Boolean` (default = `true`) — Specifies whether to manipulate the width, height, and frame rate if the camera does not have a native mode that meets the specified requirements. The default value is `true`, which means that maintaining capture size is favored; using this parameter selects the mode that most closely matches `width` and `height` values, even if doing so adversely affects performance by reducing the frame rate. To maximize frame rate at the expense of camera height and width, pass `false` for the `favorArea` parameter.

But it defaults to true and it doesn't seem to make what I want (I want to crop the image of each frame, throw away some data, and stream the rest).

Comment: Did you got the answer...
Please share if you did !!!!
Please...

Comment: @Wazzzy: No, I haven't found out a way to do this. Too bad.

Comment: @Wazzzy -- did you find out how to do it, or are you just pulling my leg? http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I will answer....I would like to share....Sorry very busy this days....Even checking SO while leaving....

Comment: @Wazzzy: Man... Come on and just spill the beans!

Comment: Damn, I've come across a need of this thing, Wazzzy, do you still remember how you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you cannot.

To crop or otherwise transform, you need to get raw video. Presence of [Camera.setKeyInterval](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setKeyFrameInterval%28%29), [Camera.setQuality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality%28%29) with bandwidth parameter and a read-only [NetStream.videoSetting](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#videoStreamSettings) that is null until a camera is connected suggests that all the compression is handled by Camera object internally while NetStream only transfers it as-is.
Similarly, [Adobe Flash Platform - Working with video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e1a.html) has no word about either transformations or compressing/decompressing video streams as data ([flash.media.VideoCodec](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/VideoCodec.html) is a mere enumeration).

Unlike this, Media Live Encoder does just that: decode the stream from camera (which needs to be in one of supported formats), optionally transform and then re-encode it.

And finally, I see browser as somewhat misplaced a location for a full-featured streaming server! It's a job for a daemon!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you after investigating the rest of the API. Thank you for the help, I'm accepting this and awarding you the bounty.